# Android: Network Request Failed when trying to upload image with fetch

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to upload an image from storage to a restful API but I keep getting Network Request Failed on Android (which means the request doesn't even go through), haven't checked on iOS because I don't need that part yet. API is already working and has been tested with Postman.

The React Native code is:

```
  body.append('vehicles',{ 
    resource_id: 2,
    resource: 'vehicles',
    cat_file_id: fileId,
    active: 1,
    vehicles: photo, //<- photo value below
    name: 'vehicles',
    type: 'image/jpeg'
  })

  fetch(`${BASE_URL}/files`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Accept: "*/*",
      Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth
    },
    body: body

  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log('IMAGE RESPONSE', response)
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('ERROR', error))
```

The photo value looks like `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/...`

The response:

```
ERROR TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.umd.js:473)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:436)
at MessageQueue.js:111
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:384)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:110)
```

On Postman the request looks something like this:

[image: Headers]

[image: Body]

**Already tried:**

- Removing Accept header
- Changing Accept value to 'application/json'
- Removing `file://` from the image url
- Added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the manifest

**Already checked:**

- No values are null or undefined
- There is a working internet connection, all other network requests on the app are working fine
- The Auth is correct

React Native version is 0.61.5

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue in both android and ios. Getting Network Failed Exception. Did you find out the solution?

Comment: I removed all headers except the auth and it started working

Answer (score 0):

I found one missing line in your code `let formData = new FormData();`. but not sure is that the exact issue here.
By the way here is a sample working code from one of my project, and I customized it with your context.

1. Add your authentication
2. replace `ImageURI` with image path and `URL_SAVE_IMAGE` endpoint url

   ```
   const newImage = {
       resource_id: 2,
       resource: 'vehicles',
       cat_file_id: 1,
       active: 1,
       vehicles: ImageURI,
       name: "my_photo.jpg",
       type: "image/jpg",
   };

   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("vehicles", newImage);

   return fetch(URL_SAVE_IMAGE, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
       },
       body: formData
   }).then(response => response.json());
   ```

it should work!

Answer (score 0):

What is your `fetch(`${BASE_URL}/files` backend server .. This usually happens when trying to connect to the backend api on the localhost machine.. Even if you use the IP address of the localhost, it still persists, so it is better to use online server for testing or just use ngrok(https://ngrok.com/) to serve your backend localhost via internet.

Answer (score 0):

in gradle.properties change the flipper version to 0.47.0

Answer (score 0):

try with Xhr, it's working as expected!

```
const URL = "ANY_SERVER/upload/image"
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url); // the address really doesnt matter the error occures before the network request is even made.
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', { uri: image.path, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg' });

  xhr.send(data);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = e => {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
      return;
    }

    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log('success', xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('error', xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow thanks for contributing, you can use `code block` for `code section` it would be good if you can format your code with 4 spaces and will make you question/answer good.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me except using the Expo FileSystem uploadAsync

```
uploadImage = async ({ imageUri } }) => FileSystem.uploadAsync(
    apiUrl,
    imageUri,
    {
      headers: {
        // Auth etc
      },
      uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
      fieldName: 'files',
      mimeType: 'image/png',
    });
```

Note - imageUri in format of file:///mypath/to/image.png

Happy days!